# Check every permutation of a number for primality

Tags: java, permutation, primes

I'm working on this problem https://projecteuler.net/problem=49 .
This is the function to check every permutation of a number(4 digit) passed to it, and check them for primality, and if there are more than 2 (ie 3) print the numbers.

the  output I'm getting is a never ending sequence of numbers. What am I doing wrong?

P.s- pretty sure it has to do with the repetition of digits, can't figure out how to work around it.

```
void checkperm(int a) {
    int w, x, y, z = 0;
    int count = 0;
    w = a % 10;
    x = (a % 100 - w) / 10;
    y = (a % 1000 - (10 * x + w) / 100);
    z = a - (y * 100 + x * 10 + w)/1000;
    System.out.println(w+x+y+z);   /*test*/
    int[] data;
    data = new int[] { w, x, y, z };
    int[] num = new int[100];
    for (int m = 0; m < 4; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
            for (int o = 0; o < 4; o++) {
                for (int p = 0; p < 4; p++) {
                    if (true) {
                        int gnaw = 1000 * data[m] + 100 * data[n] + 10 * data[o] + data[p];
                        if (checkprime(gnaw)) {
                            num[count] = gnaw;
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (count > 2)
        for (int h = 0; h < 4; h++) {
            System.out.println(num[h]);
        }

}
```

Comment: Try printing `w`, `x`, `y`, and `z`. You'll find some errors in your definitions.

Answer (score 0):

the way you're calculating w, x, y and z is wrong.

what it should be -

```
int temp = a;

w = temp%10;

temp = temp/10;
x = temp%10;

temp = temp/10;
y = temp%10;

temp = temp/10;
z = temp;
```

This is just logic correction from your code. Ideally all this should happen in a loop.

This will help assuming your rest of code is logically correct (which I haven't gone through).